# SQL Query: how to create a 'sessions' column

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I need to find a way to add a `Session` column in a `SELECT` query. I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Here's the initial example data:

```
ID    Name      VisitCounter    
1     TOM           1   
2     TOM           2   
3     TOM           3   
4     DICK          1       
5     DICK          2       
6     DICK          3       
7     DICK          4       
8     HARRY         1       
9     HARRY         2       
10    TOM           1   
11    TOM           2   
12    DICK          1       
13    DICK          2
```

I need to write a query that will add a column called 'Session' and then increment everytime the name changes and the `visitcounter = 1`.

So the query should result in this:

```
ID    Name      VisitCounter    Session
1     TOM           1               1
2     TOM           2               1
3     TOM           3               1
4     DICK          1               2
5     DICK          2               2
6     DICK          3               2
7     DICK          4               2
8     HARRY         1               3
9     HARRY         2               3
10    TOM           1               4
11    TOM           2               4
12    DICK          1               5
13    DICK          2               5 and so on
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example data, the sessions do not overlap.  If that is true in general, you could count the number of previously started sessions:

```
select  yt.ID
,       yt.Name
,       yt.VisitCounter
,       count(prev.ID) as Session
from    YourTable yt
join    YourTable prev
on      prev.ID <= yt.ID and
        prev.VisitCounter = 1
group by
        yt.ID
,       yt.Name
,       yt.VisitCounter
order by 
        yt.ID
```

[Working example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ec80/20)

Comment: Wow! I definitely have a lot to learn. This works. Thank you so much for your help on this.

Answer (score -1):

It's better to avoid data duplication in your database. I don't know if you can change database structure, but if you can, you should create two tables:

- Table "users" contains session id and user name (unique).
- Table "visits" contains visit id and user id.

Count of visits can be retrieved with a query.

Comment: I agree with this comment, but it shouldn't be an answer to the op question

Comment: Where should have I posted this? Posting large comments is uncomfortable.